# How to get all the post in the same category in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I'm coding a news website.I have 'category' in News model.

Now I want to get all the news in one of the categories named 'opinion'. But get:
**invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'opinion'**

here is part of my News model:

```
    class News(models.Model):
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cate", blank=True, verbose_name='分类')
```

here is my Category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)  # 分类名

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "分类"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is part of my view:

```
class NewsView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        opinion_news = News.objects.filter(category="opinion")

        return render(request, 'index.html', {

            'opinion_news': opinion_news,

        })
```

here is part of my index.html

```
            {% for opinion in opinion_news %}
            <li class="media">
               <h>{{opinion.title}}</h>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
```

Any friend can help?Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you show category model also?

Comment: Yes,I have update it!Thank you so much for your reply!It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default filtering by foreignkey use id field (integer). To use another field of category model use `__fieldname` syntax. For instance if `category` model has `name` field:

```
opinion_news = News.objects.filter(category__name="opinion")
```

Comment: Hi friend, could you also help me with this relative question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680988/how-to-create-link-for-one-of-the-category-in-django

Comment: Hi friend could you help with my latest question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899546/how-to-render-data-to-a-included-a-html-template-in-django