# How to create link for one of the category in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm coding a news website.I have 'category' in News model.

I want to get all the news in one of the categories named 'opinion' in my index.html. And create detail page link for each of them.

I can the title ,author, etc of the news mentioned above .But my brain really junks,I don't know how to create a link points to opinion_new.html or news_detail.htlm for each of them.I have a link for regular news to point to news_detail.htlm.

If you don't quite understand what I'm asking, please also read my last question [How to get all the post in the same category in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625049/how-to-get-all-the-post-in-the-same-category-in-django/51625060#51625060,thank) you so much!

here is part of my News model:

```
class News(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="cate", blank=True, verbose_name='分类')
```

here is my Category model:

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)  # 分类名

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = "分类"
    verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

here is part of my view:

class NewsView(View):

```
def get(self, request):
    opinion_news = News.objects.filter(category="opinion")

    return render(request, 'index.html', {

        'opinion_news': opinion_news,

    })
```

here is part of my index.html

```
        {% for opinion in opinion_news %}
        <li class="media">
          <a href='?'> <h>{{opinion.title}}</h></a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

here is part of my already works well news_detail view.

```
def newsDetailView(request, news_pk):
    news = get_object_or_404(News, id=news_pk)
    category = news.category
    tags = news.tag.annotate(news_count=Count('news'))
    all_comments = NewsComments.objects.filter(news=news)
    news.comment_nums = all_comments.count()
    news.save()

    return render(request, "news_detail.html", {
        'news': news,
        'tags': tags,
        'category': category,

    })
```

here is my url for news_detail.html

```
path('-<int:news_pk>', views.newsDetailView, name="news_detail"),
```

Comment: If I understand well, what about `<a href='{% url 'news_detail'  opinion.pk %}'> <h>{{opinion.title}}</h></a>`?

Comment: My goodness!It works!!Thanks!

Comment: very glad it works!

Comment: Hi friend,could you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779319/how-to-use-django-template-as-a-component  Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi friend,could you help with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903751/how-to-merge-same-code-block-in-django Thank you so much!