# How to use Django template as a component?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have 5 templates: **index.html, detail.html, tag.html, login.html, register.html** and a **base.html**

All 5 templates will extend **base.html**.

**index.html, detail.html, tags.html** have a same `<section>...</section>` html code section with the same data from backend.I want to add this section to **base.html**, so that don't need to repeat it 3 times in 3 different templates.

But the problem is,the **login.html and register.html** do need this section.

I know if it is React.js or Vue.js it will be very easy to use component to solve it.

Any good way to solve this question in Django?

Comment: It would be helpful if you share the contents of that section because I can't think of a use case where you need an HTML `<section>` but it doesn't exist on that web page.

Comment: Sounds like `{% include "xxx.html" %}`

Comment: @Tsang-YiShen Hey man you are right!After 2 days try.I find the best way is to use{% include "xxx.html" %}!!!!!

Comment: I came from reactjs and react native and now using django.
Looking at this question, the include tag only bring the component along with its style, right? I think that for it really work like a component we should be able to pass some styles too, like use a custom button template and change some colors and, most important, things like href. In parts, I solve it by passing a context inside the include tag and create some var tags in the template to receive the styles, but it doesnt work for the href.
Is there a solution for this or a better way for creating components in django?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**

As the OP mentioned in the comments, the requirements are quite different from what I could interpret. Thus, the fix that can be used based on my newer understanding is simply `{% include 'section.html' %}` as aptly pointed out in [Tsang-Yi Shen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779319/how-to-use-django-template-as-a-component/51780298?noredirect=1#comment90517443_51779319).

`base.html`:

```
<!-- HTML here.... -->
{% block normal_content %}{% endblock %}
```

`section.html`

```
<section>
<!-- Special Section -->
</section>
```

Wherever you want the section, just include `section.html`

`login.html` and all others which require the special section:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block normal_content %}
    Hey There!
    {% block section %}
        {% include 'section.html' %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

[Selcuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779319/how-to-use-django-template-as-a-component#51779885) explains the concept beautifully. I am adding to that answer by providing code examples for future reference.

Consider `base.html`:

```
<!-- HTML here.... -->
<!-- Common Section -->
{% block section %}{% endblock %}
{% block normal_content %}{% endblock %}
<!-- End Common Section -->
```

Now use a template for your section, `baseWithSection.html`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block section %}
<section>
....
</section>
{% endblock %}
{% block special_content %}{% endblock %}
```

For all pages that do not contain the section, extend `base.html` like so:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block normal_content %}
<!-- HTML here... -->
{% endblock %}
```

For the pages that do require the section, extend `section.html` like so:

```
{% extends 'baseWithSection.html' %}
{% block special_content %}
<!-- Special HTML here, for templates pages requiring the section -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This way dose not work.Because what I want is keeping  the special section code in the baseWithSection.html so that it can apply to many other template,but your way will let me repeat the code,so this does not solve my question.

Comment: The special section code *is* in the 'baseWithSection.html' template. The extending templates can use it as they need.

Comment: o yea, sorry my brain junks now,in my case {% block section %}{% endblock %} is inside the {% block normal_content %}{% endblock %}.Could you tell me what should I do in this situation?Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi friend can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52159365/reverse-for-news-detail-with-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-tried ?

Answer (score 6):

You can have multiple base templates. For example:

```
base.html            # Has the minimum shared elements
|
 -> base_page.html   # extends base.html (and adds your <section>...</section>)
|   |
|    -> index.html   # extends base_page.html
|    -> detail.html  # extends base_page.html
 -> login.html       # extends.base.html
 -> register.html    # extends.base.html
```